# How do I serialize the value of a Map when running mkstring?

Tags: scala

I have a map that is declared like this...

```
Map<String, SomeObject>
```

When I try to run `.mkstring` against the map I get...

```
Random String -> com.myproject.model.SomeObject@10f7c76
```

I would instead like to print out the serialized version. I have a toJson method on SomeObject that would convert it but I am not sure the proper Scala way to handle this. So I would like it to look like...

```
Random String -> {
  name: ...
  ...
}
```

How do I do this? I would prefer doing something cleaner than...

```
for ((k,v) <- propertyMap) println(k +" -> "+ v.toJson)
```

Comment: You can do `map.view.mapValues(_.toJson).mkString`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `mkString` it calls `toString`, let's see:

```scala
def mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String): String =
    addString(new StringBuilder(), start, sep, end).toString

def addString(b: StringBuilder, start: String, sep: String, end: String): StringBuilder = {
    var first = true

    b append start
    for (x <- self) {
      if (first) {
        b append x
        first = false
      }
      else {
        b append sep
        b append x
      }
    }
    b append end

    b
  }

// append calls String.valueOf(x)
def append(x: Any): StringBuilder = {
    underlying append String.valueOf(x)
    this
}

// and here Object.toString called
public static String valueOf(Object value) {
    return value != null ? value.toString() : "null"; //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

So, the problem is you should override `toString` method in `SomeObject` class to make `mkString` output more pretty.

For example, if you want to print it as json, you can call `toJson` in `toString`:

```scala
class SomeObject {
  def toJson: String = ???

  override def toString: String = toJson
}
```

after that your call `map.mkString(",")` should return

```
"Random String -> {
  name: ...
  ...
}"
```

More elegant and flexible way convert object to string without `toString` overriding is using `Show` typeclass from [`cats`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/show.html) library. Using cats you can implement `Show` instance for `SomeObject` and import it to use `show` on some collection (`map`):

```scala
import cats.Show
import cats.syntax.show._
import cats.instances.map._
import cats.instances.string._

case class SomeObject(a: String, b: String, c: Int) {
  def toJson: String = s"""{ 
    "a": "$a",
    "b": "$b",
    "c": "$c"
  }"""
}

object SomeObject {
  implicit val someObjectShow: Show[SomeObject] = new Show[SomeObject] {
    override def show(t: SomeObject): String = t.toJson
  }
}

import SomeObject._

val map: Map[String, SomeObject] = Map(
  "firstKey" -> SomeObject("a1", "b1", 0),
  "sndKey" -> SomeObject("a2", "b2", 1)
)

map.show
```

```
Map(firstKey -> {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "0"
  }, sndKey -> {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b2",
    "c": "1"
  })
```

This way has some pros:

- you can implement several times `Show` instance for `SomeObject` and import concrete implementation in necessary and when calling `show` will looking for implicit instance.
- you can use `toString` and `toJson` functions independent, you don't need to override something.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me because I want toString to serialize in human readable not JS but thank you.

Comment: @Jackie I added my answer, you can achieve `mkString` like output using `show` function.